# How can I use variables and SQL code within an SSIS package?

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, import-from-excel, dts

I have an SSIS package I am building to take data from a `.CSV` file and load it into a table in a SQL Server database. The `.CSV` file has more columns than my table and I'm looking to filter out the data based on some of these columns that are not being inserted into the table.

I have year, kind, type, dollars as my column names in the `.CSV` file but I'm only pulling type and dollars into the DB. However, I can only pull those rows where the kind= "L" and year is the current year (with one major caveat). If the process is running in the first quarter of a given year (so month <= 3) it needs to use the previous year as my qualifier for what rows it pulls in from the `.CSV` file. For instance, say it is February 2015 when this package is running, I need it to pull only rows with a year of 2014 and kind="L" from my `.CSV` file. If it is September 2015 then it needs to pull in rows with a year of 2015 and kind="L".

Any idea what the best way of doing this is? Right now I have a conditional split in my package but I can only get it to say year==YEAR(GETDATE()) and this will not work for the first quarter. I'd need some sort of variable logic to say something like `IF(currentmonth<=3 THAN @year = currentyear-1) ELSE (@year = currentyear)` and then use the @year variable in the conditional split. Is this possible?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I find that when my logic gets more and more complex, the use of the *Script* component is more and more appropriate.  I suggest using a script component to [filter your data flow based on your logic](http://sqlis.com/sqlis/post/Using-the-Script-Component-as-a-Conditional-Split.aspx).  You can control what data gets sent to what output.  (And only use the output that contains, "good" data.)

Comment: I find that when my logic gets more and more complex, use of database logic is most appropriate :) (i.e.as per @maxymoo response)

Answer (score 1):

Normally for this kind of workflow, I will import the entire CSV into a temporary table, and then have a separate SQL script or view which reads from the temporary table and applies whatever business logic is needed for the final view.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the logic to be in the SSIS package you can use a derived column component to declare a new boolean field for example `IncludeRowInOutput` and set it to be something like

```
((currentmonth <= 3 and year = year(getdate() - 1)) or (year = year(getdate))) and kind = 'L'
```

Then you can do the conditional split based on the `IncludeRowInOutput` field.

I'd normally be wary of using too much script components, I find that they are harder to debug and make the dataflow harder to understand.